# Push notification during call - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, push, apple-push-notifications

What happens if I send a push notification to the iPhone and it's during a call, or during incoming call?
would it popup on the screen and show the notification to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it gets displayed on screen and the user will need to close the notification before they can click the "End Call" button.  It's a little distracting, but does ensure that the notification has a chance at being viewed.  After all, it might be an important notification.